# Change color of object model on click - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

What I'm trying to do here is when user clicks on a particular part of object model the wireframe of that part is exposed to show which part is undergoing changes. The user can pick a color for the same part from the palette. On color selection I want that part of model to change color. Here **child.material.color.set(selectedColor)** is not working for some reason. Am I missing something? Pardon the lengthy code base.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tacchhi.com Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="palette">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Three-r80.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Projector.js"></script>
    <script>
        //GLOBAL VARIABLES
        var renderCanvas, scene, camera, renderer, cameraControl, objModel, raycaster, vector, clickInfo, marker, modelHasLoaded;

        //VIEWPORT DIMENSIONS
        var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

        function init(){
            //SCENE
            window.scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //CAMERA
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, viewportWidth/viewportHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(0, 20, 160);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            //RENDERER
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor('#ccc');

            //LIGHTING
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight('#000');
            scene.add(ambientLight);
            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight('#fff', 1, 2000);
            pointLight.position.set(-window.innerWidth, 0, 0);
            var pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight('#fff', 1, 2000);
            pointLight2.position.set(window.innerWidth, 0, 0);
            var pointLight3 = new THREE.PointLight('#fff', 1, 2000);
            pointLight3.position.set(0, viewportHeight/2, -100);
            var pointLight4 = new THREE.PointLight('#fff', 1, 2000);
            pointLight4.position.set(0, 0, 100);
            scene.add(pointLight);
            scene.add(pointLight2);
            scene.add(pointLight3);
            scene.add(pointLight4);

            //OBJECT MODEL WITHOUT MATERIALS
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setPath('obj/')
            objLoader.load('deadpool.obj', function(object){
                objModel = object;
                objModel.position.set(0, -90, 0);
                objModel.rotation.y = 300;
                objModel.name = 'ObjectModel3D';
                modelHasLoaded = true;
                scene.add(objModel);
            });

            //ORBIT CONTROLS
            cameraControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

            //RENDER AFTER OBJECT HAS LOADED
            function renderCheck(){
                if(modelHasLoaded){
                    render();
                    clearInterval(renderCheckInterval);

                    //set mouse cursor for drag/dragend
                    renderCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
                    renderCanvas.style.cursor = "url('images/grab-icon.png'), auto";
                    renderCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
                        renderCanvas.style.cursor = "url('images/grabbing-icon.png'), auto";
                    }, false);
                    renderCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
                        renderCanvas.style.cursor = "url('images/grab-icon.png'), auto";
                    }, false);
                } else {    
                    console.log('model not loaded');
                }
            }
            var renderCheckInterval = setInterval(renderCheck, 500);

            //RAYCASTING
            raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            vector = new THREE.Vector3();
            clickInfo = {
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                userHasClicked: false
            };
            window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                clickInfo.userHasClicked = true;
                clickInfo.x = event.clientX;
                clickInfo.y = event.clientY;
            }, false);

            //MARKER FOR RAYCASTING
            marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'}));

            //APPEND CANVAS
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        }

        function render(){
            //check for user clicks
            if(clickInfo.userHasClicked){
                clickInfo.userHasClicked = false;
                var x = (clickInfo.x / innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                var y = -(clickInfo.y / innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
                vector.set(x, y, 0.5); 
                vector.unproject(camera);
                raycaster.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
                if(intersects.length){
                  var target = intersects[0];

                  //place marker on click location
                  marker.position.set(target.point.x, target.point.y, target.point.z);
                  scene.add(marker);
                  applyWireframe();

                  //display color palette
                  TweenLite.to($('.palette'), 0.75, {left: '0', ease: Power4.easeOut});
                } else {
                    removeWireframe();

                    //hide color palette
                    TweenLite.to($('.palette'), 0.75, {left: '-100px', ease: Power4.easeOut});
                }
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            cameraControl.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        //APPLY WIREFRAME FOR THE SELECTED PART
        function applyWireframe(){
            var wireframeObject = scene.getObjectByName('ObjectModel3D', true);
            wireframeObject.traverse(function(child){
                if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                    child.material.wireframe = true;
                    child.material.linewidth = 1;
                    child.material.color.set('#333');
                }   
            });
        }

        //REMOVE WIREFRAME FOR THE SELECTED PART
        function removeWireframe(){
            scene.remove(marker);
            var wireframeObject = scene.getObjectByName('ObjectModel3D', true);
            wireframeObject.traverse(function(child){
                if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                    child.material.wireframe = false;
                    child.material.color.set('#fff');
                }   
            });
        }

        //SET COLOR OF OBJECT MODEL
        $('.palette span').click(function(){
            $color = new THREE.Color($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
            var selectedColor = '#' + $color.getHexString();
            var item = scene.getObjectByName('ObjectModel3D', true);
            item.traverse(function(child){
                if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                    child.material.color.set(selectedColor);
                    console.log('material color set to - ' + selectedColor);
                }
            });
        });

        window.onload = init;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a bunch of ideas:

Is selectedColor a correct hexadecimal?

Hardcode another color using **set** instead of **setHex**, just to be sure all the object is getting colored.

Call **requestAnimationFrame(render);** after your color change, it will reflect all changes you may have done, otherwise it can take some time until the scene gets refreshed.

**EDIT:**

Here it comes the red pill... maybe this is a painful solution, but is the best practice anyway in the graphics world... **you should share materials**. This means, creating beforehand all kind of needed materials and re-using the very same defined material through the whole application. This saves your application memory or overhead when creating-deleting materials. Then, create two materials for example: ObjectMaterial and SelectedObjectMaterial. Whenever your object gets selected, change its material to SelectedObjectMaterial, as soon as it is not selected anymore, re-assign to it the ObjectMaterial.

The sharing methodology applies as well to meshes and geometries, saving in this means more optimal application, better performance and clearer code.

Comment: selectedColor is correct. **set()** instead of **setHex()** not working either. The only thing that is happening is the removal of wireframe from the scene. The object model's first color still persists.

Comment: Edited answer with a different approach to get you to the solution you want to get (even through a different path)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that way also.

Comment: When I set the color of object model inside load function, the color changes. But the same code is not working on color selection. Any ideas?

Comment: I  found what the problem was. I was setting the material color inside removeWireframe function. That was why I couldn't set the object model's color inside color selection function. Now it works fine. Thanks for the input anyhow.